# Build a JSON structure for key and value pairs, where the keys changes for each item?

Tags: javascript, json, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I am using [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/), and I need to create the options which will be populated in a select box for that. I know that I can use the "inputOptions" field for that, however, and I looked at their example (from their site) below :

```
inputOptions: {
  'SRB': 'Serbia',
  'UKR': 'Ukraine',
  'HRV': 'Croatia'
},
```

Now, that is great and all, when you have a fixed set of data which is hard coded. However, in my use case, I need to be able to pull these in from a database, and my API does that already via a REST endpoint, and lets say I get it back in the following structure :

```
[
  {"key": "SRB", "value":"Serbia"},
  {"key": "UKR", "value":"Ukraine"},
  {"key": "SRB", "value":"Croatia"}
]
```

Is there an easy way to convert the bottom format to the top?

I tried iterating over it, creating a var for each one, as follows :

```
            var items = JSON.parse(listFromAPI);
            for (var item in items)
            {
              var test = { item.key : item.value };
            }
```

but that didn't seem to work? I could really use some help here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your loop, `item in items` will be the indices in the array, and not the actual items. You can a `for...of` loop, or do `for (let i in items) let item = items[i];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate over your base object and create the inputOptions as you want:

```js
var base_format = [
  {"key": "SRB", "value":"Serbia"},
  {"key": "UKR", "value":"Ukraine"},
  {"key": "HRV", "value":"Croatia"}
];

var inputOptions = {};

for (item of base_format)
  inputOptions[item.key] = item.value;
  
console.log(inputOptions);
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
var items = JSON.parse(listFromAPI);
            for (var item in items)
            {
              var test = { items[item].key : items[item].value };
            }
```

instead of

```
var items = JSON.parse(listFromAPI);
            for (var item in items)
            {
              var test = { item.key : item.value };
            }
```

Trying to make it as close to your existing code as possible.